# How to pass images has props in a vue js component (Configured with vite cause require doesnt work in vite)

Tags: vue.js, requirejs, web-component, vite, vue-props

Here is my parent component

```
<template>
<rooms-card 
roomImage="../../assets/images/room3.jpg" 
roomType="Duplex Room" 
roomDescription="Sami double bed 1 guest room 3 windows" 
roomPrice="$50/night"
/>
</template>
```

Here is the child component

```
<template>
        <div class="m-5 px-6 py-4 shadow-xl border mb-14">
        <div class="w-64 h-72 bg-red-700">
            <img :src="roomImage" class="h-full"/>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <h1 class="font-semibold text-xl my-3">{{roomType}}</h1>
            <p class="text-sm my-2 text-slate-500  w-44">{{roomDescription}}</p>
            <p>Starting from<span class="font-semibold text-xl">{{roomPrice}}</span></p>
            <button class="bg-pink-500 my-5 px-6 py-3 text-white">
                Book now
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// import { any } from "prop-types";

const props = defineProps({
  roomImage:String,
  roomType: String,
  roomDescription:String,
  roomPrice:String
})



console.log(props.roomImage)
</script>
```

NOTE: even if i use require(@/asset/images......) in my image tag src it wont work because for some reasons vite isn't configure to use requires

Answer (score -1):

Just import the asset in `<script>` and use the variable as the src attribute.

From [the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url)

> Importing a static asset will return the resolved public URL when it is served:

```html
<script setup>
import RoomImage from "../../assets/images/room3.jpg";
</script>

<template>
  <rooms-card 
    :roomImage="RoomImage" 
    roomType="Duplex Room" 
    roomDescription="Sami double bed 1 guest room 3 windows" 
    roomPrice="$50/night"
  />
</template>
```